# Is there a way to force auto deduction to consider operator <some_type>() over copy assignment?

Tags: c++, c++14, auto, type-deduction, conversion-operator

I have a variable wrapper that signals changes when the underlying variable is modified through this wrapper, so other objects can listen to changes.

It works fine (i.e. I can assign, add, subtract, call member functions on the underlying object (although these have no way of signalling changes), etc.), with one slight hiccup: if I do

```
struct some_object_type
{
  wrapper<int> some_wrapper;
}

int main()
{
  some_object_type some_object;
  auto value = some_object.some_wrapper;
}
```

`value` here is correctly deduced as a `wrapper<int>`. Is there any way to make this construct behave as if `some_object.some_wrapper` is of type `int`, so that `value` is deduced as an `int` variable?

Comment: Why would you want the type of `some_wrapper` to be deduced as `int`, when it is not an  `int`?

Comment: You could `delete` the copy constructor for `some_wrapper` and write an implicit conversion operator to `T`. Is that reasonable for you?

Comment: `auto value = ... ` is an example of copy construction, not assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TartanLlama has the correct solution in his comment.  However, what would you like `auto` to deduce to if instead you had specified `auto const& value = ...`?  The implicit conversion won't work in that case.

I've run into this problem before, and the best solution I could come up with was to provide an `wrapper<T>::operator()` function:

```
struct some_object_type
{
  wrapper<int> some_wrapper;
}

int main()
{
  some_object_type some_object;
  auto value1 = some_object.some_wrapper;  // deduces to wrapper<int>
  auto value2 = some_object.some_wrapper(); //deduces to int      
}
```

Maybe not the solution you had hoped for, but unless you forego automatic type deduction, you're best resort is @TartanLlama's suggestion.